# Hide Elements instead of Removing them

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm using `startFrom` and `limitTo` filters and they work well but these filters remove the DOM elements inside the `<tr>` and I need to access them.
**Is there any way to HIDE the DOM instead of REMOVING it?**

This post is related: [Validating paginated forms in Angular JS (1.x)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39328605/validating-paginated-forms-in-angular-js-1-x)

```js
app.filter('startFrom', function() {
        return function(input, start) {
            if (input) {
                start = +start;
                return input.slice(start);
            }
            return [];
        };
    });
```

```html
<tr ng-repeat="d in filteredData = (data | startFrom: (currentPage-1) * itemsPerPage | limitTo: itemsPerPage) track by $index">
  ...
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create another tr with ng-repeat from itemsPerPage that would also have  class="ng-hide"

Comment: Yup. ng-hide gives display:none. ng-if removes from DOM